# Creating a function to create array from file: which approach would be more efficient?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I'm considering writing a function which creates an array to house data (in the form of characters for now)  from a file using calloc.
My two most obvious options, as I understand, are reading all the characters to get the total size needed, use calloc to assign the needed space, and then use  fseek to get to the begining of the file, and fill the array before returning the pointer to the array.
The second option would be to create a small initial array continuously add realloc to add chunks as needed as I copy, and in case of realloc faliure transfer all data to a new calloc of the new, larger, size before freeing the old calloc, and once all is read returning the array pointer.

The question is really, how likely is it for realloc to fail with large data sets, as if it is not I imagine the second approach will be advantageous in such cases.

As far as I understand, creating a large array and then shrinking as needed would be trickier, so I haven't listed it as an option; if I am wrong about that please mention it.

Comment: Colud you live with only having read a part of the file? Could you only live on with having read the whole file?

Comment: It's more a theoretical question- I'd both like to know the best way to impliment a function that does that, and also to be able to read the whole file if I so wished. In practice, I'd be unlikely to use it for anything so large that the first version wouldn't work fine.

Comment: If you are reading a text file with unequal line lengths, the problem is trickier, unless you want to read the entire file into one memory block and then walk through it.

Comment: What OS?  There's really no strictly compliant OS-independent way to determine the size of a file using C.

Comment: I was thinking of reading through till EOF, and incrementing a count value to determain array size

Comment: *I was thinking of reading through till EOF, and incrementing a count value to determain array size*  The problem with doing that is you have to read the file twice.  And you say your files are large enough to make you worry about running out of memory.

Comment: "transfer all data to a new calloc the size before freeing the old calloc" - please re-phrase, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @davmac done. hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Ok, it's at least grammatically correct. But if a `realloc` fails, you expect a `calloc` of the same size to succeed? This seems unlikely. If the `realloc` fails, you should probably report failure at that point and then terminate.

Comment: @davmac I was under the impression that a realloc would try to extend the existing memory rather than find a new place in the heap, but maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons the standard says that "The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by _ptr_ and  returns  a pointer  to a new object that has the size  specified by _size_". Some implementations try to extend the existing allocation, but if they cannot they should allocate from elsewhere in the heap.

Comment: @okay thanks. So I'd just need to accept any realloc failiure as a reason to terminate. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you're judging quality by likelihood of out-of-memory or performance, the second and third cases need not be considered because the first case is a clear winner. Except don't read every character to get the total size needed. Use a binary file and seek to the end; get the position (thatll be the length) and then seek back to the start. This will be instantaneous in essentially every conceivable scenario and certainly no worse than reading every character.  Certainly however effective realloc is, it can't be any better than allocating only once. And if you were judging quality by performance, you could have already tested it by now.

Comment: To be strictly compliant, you can't use an `fseek` to the end of a binary file to find its length.  Per **7.21.9.2 The
`fseek`
function** of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  *A binary stream need not
meaningfully support
`fseek`
calls with a
`whence`
value of
`SEEK_END`
.*

Comment: `fseek()`/`ftell()` does tend to work, but the question has left off the OS.

Comment: OK fair enough.  Orangesandlemons, the approach I outlined will work on 9999 systems, so youll have to have to kick back, have a few beers, and wait for it to crash on the 10000th system and then fix that one system. Or else you can waste a bunch of time writing or copying megabytes worth of OS portability code which wont work on 9950 systems.